# A problem with a Windows service using SubSonic 3

Tags: subsonic, subsonic3

I'm trying to implement a C# Windows service, which utilizes SubSonic 3 to query and update a MSSQL database. The problem is that when I start the service, Windows Service manager says "The MyService on Local Computer started and stopped. Some services stop automatically if they are not in use by other services or programs". Application event log says that "Service cannot be started. System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Update'." followed by a stack trace.

I'm installing and starting the service as an admin. The error occurs only when the service is trying to run a query to the database. What I'm doing wrong? Any help is appreciated!

The service is developed using Visual Studio 2010 and running it as normal application works fine.

Best regards,
Aki

Answer (score 1):

The query is causing an unhandled exception, which causes your service to stop. You will need to determine what the query is that is causing the issue and try to fix that. Judging from the error message, it looks like SubSonic might be generating some invalid SQL for your query.